# TextBlock auto identify links WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, winrt-xaml

Do we have any property to auto highlight links for TextBlock or TextBox which automatically highlights the links in Text?

I can use RichTextBlock but don't know how to bind it or how I can highlight only the links in it. In my application server is giving me a long paragraph which includes 1 or 2 links, we want to highlight them as we are doing with UITextView in iOs.

Thanks,
Kavit.

Comment: Still doesn't find the answer for the question. Can anybody knows any third party tool or package which can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you? Its for the Windows Phone but its all very similar.

[How to replace link to hyperlink in RichTextBox (Windows phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516140/how-to-replace-link-to-hyperlink-in-richtextbox-windows-phone)

You could write an attached property to bind to the source text that applies this trick.