# How to have Hyper link in text block based on text in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8

We have Conversation view, in that we ll receive message and post the messages, in that i need hyper link for email id or web url and if it is contact number it is also hyperlink and when click on that navigate to call dialer along with contact number, it should be in text block,  eg: As like messaging (sms) in windows phone..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RichTextBox` . In `RichTextBox` you can have Hyperlink to display your link text.

Your need to parse your text with URL Regex to build hyperlink and textblock.

```
private static readonly Regex _parseUrls = new Regex(@"http(s)?://([A-Za-z0-9./]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Also you can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516140/how-to-replace-link-to-hyperlink-in-richtextbox-windows-phone)

Hope this helps.